# problem with starting MariaDB (for flask application)

Tags: macos, mariadb, flask-sqlalchemy

in my `Mac machine`, I am trying to make a database for my `flask application`, to do so I am using `MariaDB`.
to `install and start` I have used the following command

```
brew install mariadb   #to install
mysql.server start     #to start
```

installation was successful but when i tried to start using the mentioned command, I got this error:

```
mysql.server start
Starting MariaDB
220720 12:46:23 mysqld_safe Logging to '/opt/homebrew/var/mysql/MA013119.err'.
220720 12:46:23 mysqld_safe Starting mariadbd daemon with databases from /opt/homebrew/var/mysql
/opt/homebrew/bin/mysql.server: line 261: log_success_msg: command not found
```

in addition to checking "install successfully" message, I used the following command to enter the database environment:

```
mariadb -u root -p
```

it worked perfectly and I managed to create a database. so the question is how could i fix the issue with `starting mariaDB` (`mysql.server start`)?

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug that is now [fixed](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/commit/9c207c88c1411d1e538e8412182311de63757771#diff-69626c5fab0a5624041e6813e58c798dc380270d4cdbeb93ec04b36d88f6c688R103) but as of today, no release has been made that includes it.

You can put a `else` line before `log_success_msg` until such time as the next brew update occurs.